# Re-Opening Database Connection when fetching large set of data with Apache POI

Tags: database, spring, hibernate, apache-poi

I have to write in to an excel using Apache POI. The number of rows that I have to write on one sheet is around 57K and every time I tired doing that I am getting SQL Error and Network IO Exception. I am thinking that is because it is losing its connection.

> o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08S01
>   o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Network error IOException: Cannot assign requested address

How can I re-open my connection to the database if there is a network timeout?
HELP!!!!

Answer (score 0):

When you inserting large data using ORM you need to flush the connection. 
like
you have 57k rows

```
int i=totalRows;
for(int j=0;j<i;j++){
   session.save(thedatayouwantsave);
   if(j%1000==0){
      session.flush();
   }
}
```

or you can increase your cursor.

Comment: my case in reading... the solution you gave me is not related to my question

Comment: Sir the error is coming immediately when you go for save or after inserting some entries??
Check logs is it inserting some data. ??

Comment: I am writing in to an excel - basically rephrasing the question writing from the database to an excel using Apache poi and it throws an error because it keeps losing the DB connection @sunixi